# Eloquent query error

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5, eloquent

I am getting quite desperate with Laravel 5.4 and Eloquent Query builder.
I am trying to retrieve a user by username and password.

I ve following columns in my db: ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD

Following query is working for me:

```
$user = UserModel::where(['username' => $username])->first();
```

while this one is not:

```
$user = UserModel::where(['password' => $password])->first();
```

I am printing out both `$username` and `$password` before the query, and both are exactly what they should be.

**What can i possibly do wrong?**

EDIT:

- Yes I really do store password in plain text.
- The method is a part of API based on Zend-xmlrpc-server
- PHP does not return any error or exceptions
- Xmlrpc server return "404 Unknown error" fault response.
- Yes i am sure, that values do not contain any invisible characters and are indeed correct.
- Values are hard coded in request, i also tried hard coding them directly in query with the same result.
- I am using Oracle (11g I think), Laravel 5.4, PHP 5.6
- Value pair is correct, this username belongs to this password and both are exactly in the same form as in database.

I tried following forms of queries with same results:

```
$user = UserModel::where('password', $password)->first();   
$user = UserModel::where(['password' => $password])->first();
$user = UserModel::where('password', '=', $password)->first();
```

Variations with username lead to exactly same results as in the first one mentioned.

Comment: Do you really store passwords in plain-text?

Comment: Ok. Thing is, if the 1st one gets what you want while the second one does not then it's more of a "it can't actually find it" rather than "there's an error".

Comment: Yes i do, it is a bad practice, but this is just test case, not production.

Comment: did you getting any specific error message ?

Comment: share complete info, like schema, error and example of passwords

Comment: @apokryfos I am sure, that both values are correct, i even copy-pasted them directly from db.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there's no invisible characters (e.g. whitespaces or something) in one or the other? How are you getting those values and where are you displaying them for comparison?

Comment: Also even for testing you should not use plain text passwords. Since you're using Laravel you should use the built-in authentication system from the start. "I'll fix it later" is programmer talk for "maybe if I have time but not really"

Comment: @JYoThI I get 404 Unknown error fault response from Zend-xml-rpc server which processes the request, php does not show any errors or exceptions.

Comment: @apokryfos Values are hard coded in request, they are copy pasted from db. They do not contain any invisible characters. For displaying them i just echo them before this query happens.

Comment: do a `dd(UserModel::where(['password' => $password])->toSql())` and try running that query directly on the DB to make sure it works

Comment: @Rishi Schema is unimportant, because both values are from the same table, one works, while the other one does not. i described error in my response to JYoThl and examlpes are similar to : 'testuser' and 'testpassword'. (without apostrophes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved althought i am not exactly sure what caused it. 
Problem was, that Eloquent with oci8 driver (oracle driver) converts all column names to uppercase, but 'password' is some kind of reserved keyword and could not be converted and stayed in lowercase. While Oracle is case sensitive (for column and table names) it was not working. i changed name of 'password' column to 'passphrase' and everything worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The passwords are not saved in plain text so you must hash input first

```
$password = Hash::make('plaintext');
$result = User::wherePassword($password)->first();
```

Comment: Passwords are saved in plain text. They should not be, but they are.

Comment: Try this User::where('password', $password)->first();